# Deploying Postgres database from my Windows machine on to my heroku django app

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

Been stuck on this for a while...
I'm using Windows 7 x64, and I'm having trouble getting my postgres database to show up in my django heroku app. All parts of the heroku app except for the postgres part is working fine. 
Since I'm on windows, I can't get foreman to set up my database for heroku properly (I've also tried forego and honcho, but everything says that fcntl can't be found which is a Mac thing)... so I think I need to manually write in the dj_database_url stuff in my settings.py Heroku's guide says to put something like this (but this doesn't work for me):

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
```

According to dj_database_url https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url, in .config() I could also provide postgres://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/NAME I thought including this info might fix my problem.

However, I only have this info:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'coolname',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'pword'
    }
}
```

so I guess I should be writing:

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config(postgres:pword@??????:??????/coolname)
```

What's my port and host supposed to be?? Am I even doing the right thing here? Is there an easier way to get my postgresql database on my heroku app? Thanks for the help! I've been stuck on this for like 2 hours already T-T

EDIT:
I've discovered that heroku provides me with a ec2 instance of a postgres db. I've plugged that info into the dj_database_url.config() and now it works on heroku, but when I try things out locally (after commenting out all of heroku's stuff and setting up DATABASES to match the ec2 instance), I get 500 errors.... so now I'm stuck on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your database credentials from heroku dash board

1.Long to heroku dashboard

2.Select your application to which you want to connect

3.In the add on you could find your database name.

4.Click the database link. You will get database credentials.

I hope this might help you. I have not used my live database in local. This solution should help you. please comment if you have got any problems.

Comment: I've figured out that much, it's just that now I've got all that info plugged into DATABASES ={'default':{ stuff from heroku's dashboard. but it doesn't work locally.

Comment: Let me check it locally. And I will let you know.:)